# Sprite not changing when key is pressed - unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, sprite

Currently I'm simply trying to change the sprites candle from unlit to lit when the player has 'picked up' both the candle and the matches and the candle will 'go out' after a certain amount of time. However, when the space bar is pressed the transition from unlit to lit isn't occurring, even though the debug log is returning true when it should. I'm posting here to get some guidance as I have spent most of the day looking online and literally have no idea how to proceed. 
Basically the images I am trying to transition between are two different images which are in the sprites folder under assets.

This is what I've got so far.

```
//the two sprites transition
public Sprite unlitCandle;
public Sprite litCandle;

private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

bool pickUpMatches = false;
bool pickUpCandle = false;
float timeRemaining =5;
bool candleLit = false;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    if (spriteRenderer.sprite == null)
        spriteRenderer.sprite = unlitCandle;

}

// Update is called once per frame

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Matches"))
    {
        collision.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        pickUpMatches = true;
    }

    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("UnlitCandle"))
    {
        collision.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        pickUpCandle = true;
    } 

}

public void CandleTimer()
{
    if (candleLit == true)
    {
        timeRemaining = 5;
        timeRemaining -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (timeRemaining <= 0)
        {
            candleLit = false;
            spriteRenderer.sprite = unlitCandle;
        }
    }
}

public void ChangeSprite()
{
    if (spriteRenderer.sprite == unlitCandle)
    {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = litCandle;
    }
}

void Update () {


    if (pickUpCandle == true && pickUpMatches == true)
    {
        //Debug.Log(candleLit); 
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && !candleLit)
        {
            CandleTimer();
            ChangeSprite();
            Debug.Log(timeRemaining);
            candleLit = true;
            //Debug.Log(candleLit);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It wont solve anything, I think, but I think you might want to use GetKeyDown instead of GetKey. GetKeyDown will only happen once, while GetKey happen every fram a key is held down.

Comment: Also. Candlelit timer will never start. First you check if candlelit is false. Then you go to CandleLit method where you check if it is true. It will never be true since it will only run if it is false.

Answer (score 0):

Try comparing with a method like equals() instead of == in 
spriteRenderer.sprite == unlitCandle

Because right now you are just comparing references and not the objects.

At least I think thats the problem.

Comment: OP has an explicit reference to those sprites that he sets `spriteRenderer.sprite` to and can therefore compare to later on.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible issues with your code.  First, you are calling `changeSprite` at the top of `Update`, which means that it is unconditionally being called every frame.  Therefore, after a single frame of your candle being unlit, it will immediately change its sprite to `litCandle`.

I assume that the reason you are calling `changeSprite` every frame is in order to process the timer if you have a lit candle already.  Really, you should move the code to process the timer (your whole second `if` statement in `changeSprite`) to a separate function and name it something like `processCandleTimer`.  Call *that* at the top of `Update` and save the `changeSprite` method to only be called on the keypress.

Lastly, the issue that I suspect is giving you the most trouble is that you aren't resetting your timer, `timeRemaining`.  The first time you light the candle the timer will go down to 0 after the 5 seconds pass.  Every time `changeSprite` is run after that, you will change the sprite to `litCandle` in the first `if` statement and then *immediately* change it back to `unlitCandle` because the timer is 0 in the second.  To remedy this, you need to add a line like `timeRemaining = 5.0f;` when the key is hit.

Comment: Hi Brien,  I believe I tried what you suggested. However, when I logged the time in the console I noticed that it was stuck at 5 seconds now. Thank you very much for your reply, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try changing your if statement to `if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && !candleLit)` so it doesn't go back in if the candle is lit.  You'll also have to change `candleLit` back to false when time runs out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion again but the timer when space is pressed is still only showing 5 seconds remaining. it doesn't appear to be updating, in the console it displays 5 seconds once. I hope that makes sense. I thought the candleTimer method would have decremented the timer. Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: You need to move the `timeRemaining = 5` back to within the if statement, then move the call to `candleTimer` to the beginning of `Update`, not keeping it within the if statement